# adding char to users choice

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

Hi,I'm having a problem with this.  Here is the situation. There are 4 choices

1. [1]black
2. [2]red
3. [3]blue

For example, if the user choose any of this numbers code will print:

you choose black
here is my code so far

```
System.out.print("Course: \n[1] BSIT \n[2] ADGAT \n[3] BSCS \n[4] BSBA \n[5] NITE \n    enter course:");
course=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
```

The problem is, when I call  system.out.print(""+course); it prints the number and not the word itself?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot print the course without any kind of datastructure. If you want to relate the number to some kind of data you need to do it yourself. For example store the names in an array:

```
String[] names = {"BSIT","ADGAT","BSCS","NITE"};
```

Then reference your array with corresponding lookup:

```
//...
int course = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
System.out.println("You chose: " + names[course-1]);
```

Remember that indexing starts from zero when working with arrays so we decrease by one.

Answer (score 0):

What you do there:
1. You print out a sentence.
2. You let the user input a sentence, which you expect to contain a number and convert it as such.

The program itself has no clue that the first sentence you gave to the user is actually a selection of different things he should choose from.

What you need to to is to convert the number back to the thing it actually represented.

The easiest way would be a

```
String word;
switch(course) {
  case 1: word = "BSIT"
    break;
  case 2: word = "ADGAT";
    break;
  case 3: word = "BSCS";
    break;
  case 4: word = "BSBA";
    break;
  case 5: word = "NITE";
    break;
  default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The choice '" + course + "' is not a valid one. Only 1-5 would be legal);
}
System.out.println("The course you've chosen is: " + word);
```

That's the most straight forward way to do it here, but actually not my favorite, because it duplicates the places where the mapping is done. I would prefer to actually tell the program what those things are, like:

```
private enum Courses {
   BSIT(1), ADGAT(2), BSCS(3), BSBA(4), NITE(5);

   private int userChoice;

   private Courses(int theUserChoice) {
     userChoice = theUserChoice;
   }

   public int getUserChoice() {
     return userChoice;
   }

   public static fromUserChoice(int aChoice) {
     for (Courses course: Courses.values() {
       if (course.userChoice == aChoice) {
         return course;
       }
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("The choice '" + course + "' is not a valid one. Only 1-5 would be legal);
     }
   }
}

private static String printCourseList() {
  System.out.print("Courses: ");
  for (Courses course: Courses.values()) {
    System.out.print("[" + course.getUserChoice() + "] " + course.name() + " "); 
  }
  System.out.println();
}

public static main(String[] args) {
   printCourseList();
   Courses course = Courses.fromUserChoice(Integer.valueOf(System.console().readLine()));
   System.out.println("You're selected course is: " + course.name());
}
```

I prefer it that way because now the program actually knows that there is a special thing called 'Courses'. It knows that it is bound to a number and that some numbers might actually reflect a choice of a courses. It is done in a central place (the definition of the courses).

Hopefully this is not too much information and you'll see this as helpful.

Comment: Okay t-my's version is even shorter than the one I called 'straight forward'. What you do from there mostly depends on how often do you need this? Is it is done a single time and you just want to do this job now as quickly a possible. Go for the easiest (or shortest) solution.  If 'Courses' are an important thing in your program you want to pass around? Go for the separate data structure (type) - the enum solution. It's worth it in the long run!

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    switch(course)
        {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("black");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("red");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("blue");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("invalide number"); // this will execute if course var does not equale to 1 , 2 or 3
            break;

        }
```